# My sidebar is move under content blog when i publish post

Tags: wordpress

i have a issue in my blog

My sidebar is move under content blog when i publish post, but when i save draft it normal.

Here is the link : https://digitalbyrick.com/ya/

Please helping me to fix it to normal

Answer (score 0):

The width of the element ".has-shadow" is set to a fixed width of 1050px. The width of the ".widget-area" element in your sidebar is set to 280px. This causes the content to overlap as you shrink the screen. These values should be percentages or a "max-width: 100%" CSS rule should be applied to make them fit inside their containers.